# Redux form not getting re-rendered

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, redux, dropdown, redux-form

I have a dynamic dropdown. I am fetching the dynamic values in componentWillMount method and setting in state. I'm setting the fetched values to props in mapStateToProps. 
Field:

`<Field
        name="productId"
        component={this.renderDropdown}
 />`

The problem that I am facing is when the state is updated with new values, the render method is called but the renderDropdown method is not getting called. So the dropdown is not getting populated with the values that I fetched.

Is there anything extra that I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the new data as props to Field . The props will get merged with Field default props. Some thing like this

```
<Field
        name="productId"
        component={this.renderDropdown}
        newData={newData}
 />

and access the newData props in your component defined in this.renderDropdown
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Can you please explain how this worked?

Comment: Basically Field Component provided by redux-form  stays between your host elements such as <input />. This component will merge all the extra props to the default props e.g active.dirty, error. here extra props are name and newData. Field component actually passes  merged props to component. Redux-form is higher order provides you higher order component. You can read this article to understand. https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.do3h4kouk.